# Touchpad tapping is holding and dragging instead of clicking

Tags: windows, laptop, touchpad

Sometimes, my laptop (Windows 8.1, Acer) decides to change how it interprets touchpad tapping. Normally, touchpad tapping will function as a click, but sometimes the computer seems to temporarily decide to interpret a touchpad tap as a hold and drag. It will then continue to malfunction until the computer is power cycled. Clicking still works on the touchpad mouse buttons, and on a USB-connected mouse, so it's not a problem with clicking itself, but the mechanism that handles interpretation of mousepad tapping.

I am hoping there is a solution to this problem other than restarting the computer every time this happens. A permanent solution would be even better, though it's understandable that it may not be possible.

Comment: Now I just have to solve the problem of two-finger touchpad scrolling mysteriously not working. :-P

Comment: You may have an electronic or mechanical failure in the touchpad. I've seen a couple instances where there was barely evidence of a small impact on a specific location, which changed the electronic characteristics of the pad, rendering it similar to your woes.

Answer (score 1):

Every touchpad I have used drags and drops files and folders to random locations, unless you turn of tap and drag function from settings. In some cases you need to turn off tap to click, but then you must use pad buttons to click.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/4enidt/taptoclick_acting_as_touch_and_drag/)'s suggestion to look at accessibility settings, I found something that solved my problem in this particular instance:

1. Open Control Panel and searched for "Mouse", clicking on the top heading of the first result (labelled "Mouse").
2. Check and uncheck the box next to "Turn on ClickLock", pressing the "Apply" button after both toggles.

Comment: Unfortunately this only worked for 2 minutes. :-( Then it reverted and this no longer solved it.